# Flutter Android Permissions

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a task manager application in Flutter, so, is possible grant access to GET_TASKS, FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES and KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permissions with Flutter?

Comment: Go to `android/app/src/main`, add `uses-permission` entries to `AndroidManifest.xml`, it's not any different from native development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path of AndroidManifest.xml YourProject\Android\app\src\main 
You can put your permission in it 
You can see Picture below

[image]